# Support the Swift language with syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

The Swift language isn't listed in [the complete list of every identifier that you can use in the language hint for syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/263422).

Currently, the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tag is configured for `default` language hint (so using `<!-- language: swift -->` is the same as `<!-- language: default -->`). But that's not enough for Swift, as it won't colorize keywords correctly like:

```
func
guard
protocol
extension
fileprivate
open
mutating
inout
fallthrough
typealias
willSet
didSet
subscript
Self
convenience
required
init
deinit
unowned
lazy
defer
optional
associatedtype
prefix
infix
```

It will also wrongly recognize some keywords which *aren't* existing in Swift:

```
union
select
```

I understand that internally, Stack Exchange uses [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), but I also noticed that the [Swift extension for Prettify does exist](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/tree/master/src). Sadly, it doesn't seem installed yet on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Note that it would be `<!-- language: lang-swift -->`, not `<!-- language: swift -->`.

Comment: @Xufox Specifying a tag name there looks up the tag and uses the language assigned to that tag.

Comment: @animuson I know. I don’t really see how this relates to my comment.

Comment: @Xufox once `lang-swift` is added to Stack Exchange, then `<!-- language: swift -->` will be the same as `<!-- language: lang-swift -->` instead of `<!-- language: default -->`

Comment: Ah, that’s what you mean.

Comment: This would be good, especially because the `#selector`s turning to gray due to `#` being a comment in default.

Comment: @paper1111 - useful comment. That's really the only syntax/code issue that matters to me. If it's trivial to add this - and one could believe it is - it would be much appreciated.

Comment: We need to add prettify support before adjusting the tag defaults - that JavaScript change (addition) will be in the next deploy, then we can wrap this up.

Comment: Apple is gonna be dead eventually coz Steve died.. No need to include. a phone without headphone slot? Rofl.. dongles!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Done! The prettifier for Swift is now installed and working.

Comment: Thanks. I made a pull request to Google to add the missing keywords: https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/487