# Syntax highlighting for Java properties?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Is there a syntax highlighting language hint (`<!-- language: lang-??? -->`) for [Java properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties)? Or can a hint for another language/format be used for this purpose?

Example snippet to which syntax highlighting is to be added:

```
# line comment
! also a line comment (but less commonly used)
key1 = value A
key2=value B
key\ with\ spaces = lorem ipsum
url = https://meta.stackoverflow.com/
multi.line = multi \
          line value!
unicode = tab\u0009separated\u0009value
```

#### Update:

This question is not a duplicate of the very general question [*What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274371/6505250) I know the [list of supported language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109) and I tried all of them without success before I asked this question. Unfortunately, the list is incomplete: for example, `lang-xquery` which is supported by Stack Overflow is missing.

However, the language hint I know that comes closest is `lang-ini` (also missing on the list):

`<!-- language: lang-ini -->`

```ini
# line comment
! also a line comment (but less commonly used)
key1 = value A
key2=value B
key\ with\ spaces = lorem ipsum
url = https://meta.stackoverflow.com/
multi.line = multi \
          line value!
unicode = tab\u0009separated\u0009value
```

In cases with URLs as values or with `! ...` line comments I would prefer `<!-- language: lang-none -->` instead.

Comment: (This was on the main page due to the reopen. The syntax highlighter [changed in September 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) (but probably not the outcome).)

Comment: I want this too, It's frustrating that archived text-editors have this functionality but not the latest Stack Overflow.

Comment: Here's a MSO post requesting support for this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372584/java-properties-file-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 2):

No. The languages supported by our syntax highlighting engine are listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109).

There is obviously nothing for Java .properties files, and I don't see anything that would be suitable.

Perhaps Bash comes closest; at least it gets the most common form of line comments correct?

Comment: If nothing matches `lang-none` might be the least confusing ...

Comment: Indeed. Is there a tag that this is associated with? If so, I can make `lang-none` the default syntax highlighting for that tag. I didn't find one, though. No [[tag:java-properties]], and [[tag:properties]] is much more general.

Comment: The syntax highlighting engine list seems to me to be incomplete, at least [lang-query](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-xq.js) is missing.

Comment: I suspect that questions would 9 out 10 also be tagged with [tag:java] in which case the major tag's language hint takes precedence. I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @howlger not every available lang gets included in the SE supported set.

Comment: @rene What do you mean by _included_? Added to the syntax highlighting engine list or can not be used?

Comment: There are languages supported by Google Code Prettify that are *not* supported by the fork of Prettify that Stack Exchange uses. I'm not sure how this decision is made. Probably balancing frequency of usage with size of the JavaScript payload being downloaded on each request. You can ask the team to add support for a language if it's supported by Google Code Prettify by posting a [[meta-tag:feature-request]], as was done [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348895/support-the-swift-language-with-syntax-highlighting) for Swift. @howlger

Comment: @howlger the SE devs hand pick the lang extensions they want to include/support on the site. They don't do a pull of the Github repo and then bundle everything found in there. So a lang extension being available in the GitHub repo doesn't mean it is *missing*, it means either no-one requested support for it, or in testing that particular lang extension caused trouble.

Comment: @rene Note, with Java syntax highlighting values that contains `//` (e. g. URLs) will be partly displayed as comments.

Comment: @howlger yes, programming languages are not parse-able by a regular expression, which is what prettify mainly uses. So it will stumble now and then.

Comment: @CodyGray `lang-xq` is supported by Stack Overflow but it is not on the list (I tried to add it to the list, but it doesn't seem to have been accepted).

Comment: @howlger I see no evidence that `lang-xq` is supported by Stack Overflow. Where did you find that? It is causing the code to be highlighted with the `default` highlighter.

Comment: @rene As you said before, most questions are tagged with [java]. If values contain URLs it looks worse with than without Java syntax highlighting. As a workaround `<!-- language: lang-none -->` must be added manually.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think so. If I add a XQuery snippet to my question here, it will be not highlighted. Also with `<!-- language: lang-none -->` or `<!-- language: lang-foo -->` the snippet is not highlighted. In contrast, with `<!-- language: lang-xq -->` the snippet is highlighted. From this I conclude that `lang-xq` is supported by Stack Overflow.

Comment: @howlger that is strange because there is no lang-xq [here](http://dev.sstatic.net/Js/prettify-full.en.js). I expect you see lang-default and I explain [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327677/578411) what that does.

Comment: @rene That doesn't explain why it is different with `<!-- language: lang-foo -->` (no highlighting) and <!-- language: lang-xq -->` (correct highlighting). See also my updated question.

Comment: @CodyGray Is the syntax highlighting in the second code snippet (below _Update_) visible to you? Yes? It is marked with `<!-- language: lang-ini -->` which is not listed. That contradicts your thesis.

Comment: Yes, I see syntax highlighting for `lang-ini`. I see the exact same highlighting for `lang-xq`, `lang-xquery`, and `lang-foo`. This all comes from the `default` syntax highlighting, where Prettify just guesses and highlights for some kind of "standard" language syntax. It is wildly inaccurate. The only thing that it gets right is that `#` starts a comment. The bottom of the Meta Stack Exchange answer that I linked shows you how to confirm whether Stack Overflow supports a particular syntax highlighter: go [here](http://dev.sstatic.net/Js/prettify-full.en.js) and look for it. @howlger